# Why disabling interrupt makes your code run even slower?

Tags: linux-kernel, benchmarking

I was doing a little bit benchmark of how efficient `do_gettimeofday()` and `getnstimeofday()` run in the kernel. I did the experiment by compiling a kernel module and use the following code in the `module_init` function:

```
int i;
struct timeval st, en, diff;
struct timespec s, e, dif;

do_gettimeofday(&st);
for (i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
     do_gettimeofday(&en);
diff.tv_sec = en.tv_sec - st.tv_sec;
if (en.tv_usec < st.tv_usec) {
    diff.tv_usec = 1000000 + en.tv_usec - st.tv_usec;
    diff.tv_sec--;
}
else
    diff.tv_usec = en.tv_usec - st.tv_usec;

getnstimeofday(&s);
for (i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    getnstimeofday(&e);
dif = timespec_sub(e, s);

printk("do_gettimeofday: %d times in %lu.%06lu\n", i, diff.tv_sec, diff.tv_usec);
printk("getnstimeofday: %d times in %lu.%09lu\n", i, dif.tv_sec, dif.tv_nsec);
```

On an AR9331 based development board I got the following output from dmesg:

```
do_gettimeofday: 10000000 times in 4.452656
getnstimeofday: 10000000 times in 3.170668494
```

However, if I disable interrupt by enclosing my code between `local_irq_save` and `local_irq_restore`, i.e. do the following

```
local_irq_save(flags);
...{run the above code}...
local_irq_restore(flags);
```

and run the above code, I got the following output instead:

```
do_gettimeofday: 10000000 times in 5.417230
getnstimeofday: 10000000 times in 3.661163701
```

To my understanding, running the code with interrupt enabled should have prolonged running time (e.g. an interrupt triggered when the code is running, the CPU jumps to the interrupt handler and jumps back later). It feels weird that the code ran even slower with all the interrupt disabled on the device. Could anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: And who is updating your time? You may completely disable the interrupts and check the result. It might give a clue.

Comment: I think the device has an internal clock source which is independent of the OS kernel, and getnstimeofday() gets time from the hardware clock instead of from the jiffies in the kernel. As I said in the question, I should have already disabled all interrupts when I did the 2nd benchmark.

Comment: I meant *completely* disable them. You did it only for local CPU.

Comment: That device has only one CPU. Do you mean disable interrupts on the device's interrupt micro controllers? (I don't even know how to do this)

Comment: Do you mean one CPU with one core? In such case it's very interesting what `local_irq_disable()` does.